# Change over old Sharepoint to the new updated Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I'am interning at a company and my task is to update their old sharepoint website. I created a new sharepoint website ("my-site".sharepoint.com/site/"my-site"/SitePages/Home.aspx)  that has the functionality that i am looking for. The site has the url: "my-site".sharepoint.com/sitepages/home.aspx. Is there a way I can make the 'Top-site' of the new sharepoint site have the url link of the old one. If not should I completely trash the old site and build it up to my standards.

Thank you, 
Ray

Answer (score 1):

if you have Mysites as the home url it seems to me that you created a personal site, those cannot be shared public

sharepoint sites created under sites cannot be made into Top sites.

you have two options 
1 : make the updates on the old sites.
2 : create a new site collection at the web application level (from central administration)

next, Changing the URl

if you want to change the URL of the site, first you have to become that URL available , for that you would need to copy the site to a new location using powershell

once you copied your site, then you can delete the original and copy your brand new site to the now available old url